# ¿Cómo integro el advanced credit and debit card payments de PayPal?

Tags: paypal

estoy tratando de seguir las instrucciones de la documentación de PayPal:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/advanced-card-payments/

Pero no me funciona (Además que el link del Step 1 está roto), mirando el código, la linea `paypal.HostedFields.isEligible()` me retorna false lo que hace que se oculte mi formulario de cobro, ¿Alguien sabe por qué pasa esto? ¿O Cómo puedo hacer que mi cuenta sea elegible?

Estoy usando el Default App junto a la cuenta bussiness que genera por defecto PayPal en el ambiente sandbox. El código es el mismo que proporciona PayPal en su documentación. Le estoy pasando el id del cliente correctamente.

Comment: Que has intentado? (código)

Comment: Literal lo único que intenté fue copiar y pegar el código tal cual lo tiene PayPal e investigar en su documentación el método isEligible() sin encontrar respuestas. Me puse en contacto con el soporte de PayPal y me acaban de responder que este tipo de integración no está disponible en México, así que me tocará hacer otro tipo de integración.

Answer (score 0):

después de ponerme en contacto con el soporte de PayPal, me comentaron que este tipo de integración no está disponible para México (Aunque en los resultados de la búsqueda de PayPal aparezca que si)

Así que al final tocará hacer otro tipo de integración.